# preprocessor directive in while condition not working

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

when trying to use a variable defined in a preprocessor directive:

```
  #define TIME_CONST 20;
```

in a while condition:

```
  while(i<TIME_CONST){...}
```

I get an error complaining about parantheses...

when i use:

```
  while(i<20)
```

everything works fine.

what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If using C++ it is wise not to use `#define` - Put `const int TIME_CONST=20;` in the header file instead. The compiler rather than the preprocessor is a lot better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define TIME_CONST 20;
```

Remove `;` from the end.

Because of `;`, the following:

```
while(i<TIME_CONST){...}
```

becomes this:

```
while(i< 20;){...}
```

which is wrong, isn't it?

In C++ (and C), macros are *text-replacement* mechanism, so any usage of `TIME_CONST` will be replaced by `20;` because that is how it has been defined.

An advice: **avoid macro as much as possible** . You've better alternative in C++. Use `const` (or `constexpr` ) to define your *really constant* object:

```
const int TIME_CONST = 20;
```

Now `;` is fine, infact *required* by the language.